# Network sharing with OSX

Tags: networking, filesystem

How can I create a network share between Elementary OS and OS/X?

In OS/X I see no hint of Elementary on the network.

In Elementary I see two entries for my MBP under `Network|Entire Network`. 
Both of these options both prompt me for a password with a dialog that specifies `Domain=WORKGROUP` (which seems very windowsy to me). After putting in the correct password, I'm told that the password is wrong. If I set Domain to blank, the connect button is disabled.

Comment: Did you enable _Media Library_ in _System Settings_?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, all you need is **samba**.

1. You have to install it first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba python-glade2 gksu
   ```
2. create special user for sharing files, open the application from slingshot and configure the shared folder;
3. and don't forget to restart the services

   ```
   sudo restart smbd && sudo restart nmbd
   ```

Comment: this works great for accessing files from the mac to the elementary os install, but this solution still does not allow me to access macintosh shares from the elementary os system

Comment: clarification for the answer above ... you need to create the samba/CIFS share on OS X then mount it on linux
you may want to install the mac server package ... I think I remember that it handles samba